# Ubuntu Webhooks is not reading the correct RVM ruby installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, ubuntu, webhooks

I'm trying to set up [webhooks](https://github.com/adnanh/webhook) on my system to do some ruby stuff on my machine automatically via running a bash script. The problem is that the ruby used while running the script manually differs from the one running using hooks.

Here is a simple bash script printing ruby values (test-ruby.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Tetsing...'
ruby -v;
which ruby;
bundle -v;
which bundle;
```

Below is the output if I run it via sh test-ruby.sh
[image]

Below is the output from triggering same script via hooks
[image]

**Caveats:**

- Ubuntu version is 22.
- Ruby is installed via RVM.

Comment: Why is this tagged _bash_? There is no bash involved in your code example (though the difference between bash and sh should not matter in your case).

Comment: For debugging, I would put an `id` in your script, so that we know whether in both cases the script is executed as the same user.

Comment: @user1934428 the tagged bash has been added based on webhooks documentation guidelines:

'Make sure that your bash script has #!/bin/sh shebang on top.' https://github.com/adnanh/webhook

Comment: @user1934428
Without the tagged has, the whole script is failing:

"error occurred: fork/exec /root/test-ruby.sh: exec format error"

Comment: Think logically: If you want it to be a bash script, you will either put a #!/bin/bash as the first line, **or** you will invoke it as `bash SCRIPTNAME` (depending on your preferences).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1 The top of the file should be

```
#!/bin/bash
```

#2 Force loading the rvm env on the top of the script

```
[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session as a function
```

Comment: Trying it out...

Comment: Working like a charm! You made my may. Literally I spent 6 hours trying to solve it out.